# FileAppender does not work with File property?

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Using log4net 1.2.11 on .net framework 3.5, this works:

```
var fileAppender = new log4net.Appender.FileAppender(layout, "check.log", true);
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)).Info("constructor");
```

Except that it gives the warning:

> Warning   1   'log4net.Appender.FileAppender.FileAppender(log4net.Layout.ILayout,
>   string, bool)' is obsolete: 'Instead use the default constructor and
>   set the Layout, File & AppendToFile properties

But if I use the properties it does not work

```
var fileAppender = new log4net.Appender.FileAppender() 
    { Layout = layout, File = "check.log", AppendToFile = true };            
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileAppender);
log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program)).Info("prop1");
```

That is, nothing gets written to the file. I have also tried a full path ("c:\check.log") and assigning to properties after creating the appender with default constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try it but looking at the log4net source code I can only assume that you need to call `ActivateOptions` on the file appender in order to make things work.

Comment: That's what it was. So I still need two lines, with the ctor paramaters `ActivateOptions` does not need to be called.